# Zabbix LLD and Discovery Rule

Tags: zabbix

I have a script with below result :

```
{
        "data":[

            { "{#label}":"string1"  },
            { "{#label}":"string2"  },
            { "{#label}":"string3"  },
            { "{#label}":"string4"  },
            { "{#label}":"string5"  },
            { "{#label}":"string6"  },
            { "{#label}":"string7"  }

            ]
}
```

create the new Discovery rule with "External Script" type in zabbix but this object is "not supported" with message : "Value should be a JSON object."

what is my script problem ?

Comment: You haven't specified your Zabbix server version, but in [this Zabbix bugreport][1] you opened it has been clarified as 3.0.7.

Please also note that the LLD variable names must be uppercase - if you fix that, does it work?

  [1]: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-12214

Comment: yes , it works , thanks a lot